# Exclude python list containing filenames in os.walk

Tags: python, xml

My settings.Mediaroot contains abc.xml,xyz.xml,pqr.xml,lmn.xml. I should be able to exclude abc.xml and xyz.xml and parse only pqr.xml and lmn.xml

```
exfiles=['abc.xml','xyz.xml']

def locatexml(pattern,exfiles=None):
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.MEDIA_ROOT):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        yield os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Comment: So then don't yield them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def locatexml(pattern,exfiles=None):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.MEDIA_ROOT):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            if filename not in exfiles:
                yield os.path.join(path, filename)
```

you can also make a `set` from exfiles to faster check

```
def locatexml(pattern,exfiles=None):
    exfiles = set(exfiles)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(settings.MEDIA_ROOT):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            if filename not in exfiles:
                yield os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Comment: I should not do os.walk on exfiles=['abc.xml','xyz.xml'] but it should walk through other files in the same directory i.e pqr.xml and lmn.xml.

Comment: Roman Pekar Thank You very much. It works fine.